# Automatically wrapping dynamically added object properties (functions) in a wrapper function

Tags: javascript, jquery, typeof, object-literal

I use this setup to add properties to an object:

```
var obj = {
    extend: function(key, obj){
        this[key] = obj;
    }
}
```

This works well. However, in some cases i want to add sub-objects as properties:

```
obj.extend('new', {
    test: function(){
        console.log('test called');
    }
});
```

I would like to automatically wrap all functions occurring in the object passed (as second parameter) to `obj.extend()` in a function which in itself wraps the actual call of the function in `$(document).ready(function(){})`

My approach was this:

```
extend: function(key, obj){
    for(var prop in obj){
        if(typeof prop == 'function') {
            console.log(prop + ' is a function'
        } else 
            console.log(prop + ' is NOT a function');
        }
    }
    this[key] = obj;
}
```

But `typeof prop` seems to return `string` and not 'function'. I have checked a variety of articles and posts but the approach:

```
typeof propertyOfObject == 'function'
```

seems totally valid.

What am i doing wrong here? Why does `typeof propertyOfObject` give me 'string'? How can i check if `prop` is a function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you're just iterating over the `Object keys`, not its properties.

You need to fully qualify the property to access it:

```
if( typeof obj[ prop ] === 'function' ) { }
```